# Error in Amadeus Service: A header representing a Message Addressing Property is not valid and the message cannot be processed

Tags: c#, web-services, c#-3.0, amadeus

While trying to invoking my Amadeus Fare_masterpricetravelboard Service using SoapUI like mozila poster, Google restclient app, or my .net code, it returns the following error message:

> A header representing a Message Addressing Property is not valid and the message cannot be processed

The same webservice is working fine in SOAP UI Tool.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Security_v1" xmlns:typ="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Types_v1" xmlns:iat="http://www.iata.org/IATA/2007/00/IATA2010.1" xmlns:app="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/AppMdw_CommonTypes_v3" xmlns:link="http://wsdl.amadeus.com/2010/06/ws/Link_v1" xmlns:ses="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Session_v3" xmlns:fmp="http://xml.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_10_3_1A">
  <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <add:MessageID xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">65449120-2aa0-46b0-9dcc-c40c6439836c</add:MessageID>
    <wsa:Action>http://webservices.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_10_3_1A</wsa:Action>
    <add:To xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/1ASIWIBEWWZ</add:To>
    <link:TransactionFlowLink xmlns:link="http://wsdl.amadeus.com/2010/06/ws/Link_v1" />
    <oas:Security xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <oas:UsernameToken oas1:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <oas:Username>WSWWZIBE</oas:Username>
        <oas:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">EoCeDbDbThB=</oas:Nonce>
        <oas:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">Hr2HRG8j0dTH19kh52wQ5aqMxhU=</oas:Password>
        <oas1:Created>2014-07-19T12:33:47:530Z</oas1:Created>
      </oas:UsernameToken>
    </oas:Security>
    <AMA_SecurityHostedUser xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Security_v1">
      <UserID POS_Type="1" PseudoCityCode="THRI4213V" RequestorType="U" />
    </AMA_SecurityHostedUser>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch>
      <numberOfUnit>
        <unitNumberDetail>
          <numberOfUnits>1</numberOfUnits>
          <typeOfUnit>PX</typeOfUnit>
        </unitNumberDetail>
        <unitNumberDetail>
          <numberOfUnits>250</numberOfUnits>
          <typeOfUnit>RC</typeOfUnit>
        </unitNumberDetail>
      </numberOfUnit>
      <paxReference>
        <ptc>ADT</ptc>
        <traveller>
          <ref>1</ref>
        </traveller>
      </paxReference>
      <fareOptions>
        <pricingTickInfo>
          <pricingTicketing>
            <priceType>RP</priceType>
            <priceType>RU</priceType>
            <priceType>TAC</priceType>
          </pricingTicketing>
        </pricingTickInfo>
      </fareOptions>
      <itinerary>
        <requestedSegmentRef>
          <segRef>1</segRef>
        </requestedSegmentRef>
        <departureLocalization>
          <departurePoint>
            <locationId>CDG</locationId>
          </departurePoint>
        </departureLocalization>
        <arrivalLocalization>
          <arrivalPointDetails>
            <locationId>LHR</locationId>
          </arrivalPointDetails>
        </arrivalLocalization>
        <timeDetails>
          <firstDateTimeDetail>
            <timeQualifier>TA</timeQualifier>
            <date>041114</date>
            <time>2200</time>
            <timeWindow>4</timeWindow>
          </firstDateTimeDetail>
          <rangeOfDate>
            <rangeQualifier>C</rangeQualifier>
            <dayInterval>1</dayInterval>
          </rangeOfDate>
        </timeDetails>
      </itinerary>
    </Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soap:Envelope>
 <soap:Header>
<wsa:Action>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>
<wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:0ce4ebc0-7753-6394-4945-c7e8f81c2c49</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:RelatesTo RelationshipType="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/reply">65449120-2aa0-46b0-9dcc-c40c6439836c</wsa:RelatesTo>
 <wsa:FaultDetail>
<wsa:ProblemHeaderQName>wsa:To</wsa:ProblemHeaderQName>
<wsa:ProblemIRI>https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/1ASIWIBEWWZ</wsa:ProblemIRI>
 </wsa:FaultDetail>
 </soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
 <soap:Fault>
<faultcode>wsa:InvalidAddressingHeader</faultcode>
<faultstring>A header representing a Message Addressing Property is not valid and the message cannot be processed</faultstring>
<faultactor>SI:muxDZ1</faultactor>
 </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: how did you send request to amadeus

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Be sure that the url of the web request matches the value of the tag "add:To", including letter case.

Probably you are developing in .net and, even if you set the url in the same letter case, the request will  be sent to the address in lowercase. So **nodeD1** become **noded1** in http layer but remains nodeD1 in soap envelope. Be careful to use lowercase or uppercase in both fields

Comment: Great, you saved me a few more days of hair loss.

Comment: The comment about the lowercase is correct. Solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of SOAPAction as well.

In my case ,

1. Soap UI internally uses : [http://webservices.amadeus.com/{{orgCode}}/FMPTBQ_21_4_1A](http://webservices.amadeus.com/%7B%7BorgCode%7D%7D/FMPTBQ_21_4_1A)
2. when generating stub, orgCode is missed it came as http://webservices.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_21_4_1A

After changing SoapAction explicitly in the code, started working.